# Hangfire in ASP.Net Core : simple recurring job does not refresh its dynamic content

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

I am trying to implement cron task on a web application in ASP.Net Core 1.1.

I decided to choose the [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) library.

In order to check if my installation and configuration were working fine, I just wrote a very simple recurring job, aimed to print the current DateTime on the console output :

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}"), Cron.Minutely);
```

The weird thing is that every minute, it prints the **same message**, corresponding to the date and time of the first time the message was printed, and not updating the `DateTime.Now` part.

If I access the /Hangfire dashboard, and look at the job details, it appears translated as static datetime output, as such :

```
Console.WriteLine("15/09/2017 15:27:21");
```

So the job seems to be kind of 'compiled' when enqueued and this is obviously not what I intended to do.

I tried to replace this job by a job counting rows on a database table. And the problem is the same : if I add or remove rows between two occurences of the job, the row count displayed is not updated. Update only occurs if I restart the web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your problem is that Hangfire serializes the arguments you send to the job using NewtonSoft. When your program enqueues the job, it gets the current time, and then will call that function with that time.

Try moving the function into a method call. So instead of

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}"), Cron.Minutely);
```

Try

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => PrintTime(), Cron.Minutely); 
...
private static void PrintTime() {
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}");
}
```

If my understanding of Hangfire is correct, this will only serialize the name of the method to call, but not serialize the time.

Comment: Actually your answer would probably provide the same output, for another reason, but I have understood why and solved (will post the answer). Static method in a static class was my issue. Once I moved my method to a class instanciated at each execution, everything went fine. And for this specific case, I think you identified the issue.

Comment: @kall2sollies I can confirm that it would work, as per [a quick test](https://shifty.site/JiBYF).
An application I'm working on has a few layers on it, but all the hangfire processes are started via a public method in a public static class. The important takeaway is that information provided to hangfire in its Enqueue/AddOrUpdate methods is a snapshot of what will be sent to the methods. What _actually_ happens within those methods, and what is generated within those methods, is determined when that method is ran.

Comment: I think maybe my first try was a pitfall. My static class was meant to hold extension methods for the Configure method of a Startup class in an ASP.Net project, the job registering was in this extension method, and the called method was in another static method in the same static class. Anyway, what matters the most is that when properly implemented, it all works ! Thanks for the effort !

Answer (score 2):

For the issue described in my question, Stephen Vernyi has spotted the issue : since Hangfire serializes parameters in JSON, the first datetime was frozen when serialized, so that each subsequent execution would provide the same output.

But one must be careful when writing a method, as he suggested.

Since I was casually trying to have this all work, all my tests where written within a static class with static methods. And such implementation had provided the same frozen datetime issue !

When I decided to refactor my implementation, with Job services, registered in the default ASP.Net Core IoC container, and set up to provide new service instances at every request, it not only solved the frozen output issue, but also every issue encountered with Dependency injections.