# How to running a DateTime-based Recurring Job Using Hangfire?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, hangfire

I'm using Hangfire in an ASP.NET Core app. I want to run a job like this:
`() => Console.WriteLine($"Triggered At {DateTime.Now.ToString()} !!")` every minute. I expect to get this result:

```
Triggered At 5/16/2020 3:05:40 PM
Triggered At 5/16/2020 3:06:40 PM
Triggered At 5/16/2020 3:07:40 PM
Triggered At 5/16/2020 3:08:40 PM
```

but I get the result as follow:

```
Triggered At 5/16/2020 3:05:40 PM
Triggered At 5/16/2020 3:05:40 PM
Triggered At 5/16/2020 3:05:40 PM
Triggered At 5/16/2020 3:05:40 PM
```

I have used this code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
    app.UseHangfireDashboard();

    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("TestJob",
        () => Console.WriteLine($"Triggered At {DateTime.Now.ToString()} !!"), "* * * * *");

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should wrap it inside a method.

[Hangfire serializes arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240864/hangfire-in-asp-net-core-simple-recurring-job-does-not-refresh-its-dynamic-con)

```cs
public static void Method() {
   Console.WriteLine($"Triggered At {DateTime.Now.ToString()} !!");
}

 RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("TestJob",
        () => Method(), "* * * * *");
```